# dotCMS content missing after Save / Publish

Tags: html, dotcms

I had a page that was a blank template with only a simple weather.com widget on it. Something simple like

```
<script> //something here </script>
```

I updated it to be

```
<title> Some title </title>
<script> //something here </script>
```

Then hit "Save / Publish". Now nothing is showing up. Not even the content container. Is there any way I can get that content back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed a closing tag on that `<title>`. Go to your website and check the title.

You can always rename your current page to something like `page-name-old` and create a new page called `page-name`(the original page name). If you can't remember what your old page code was, just view source via your browser, and copy it over (hopefully it was something simple).

Then when you publish `page-name`, you can just archive `page-name-old`.